# Kibana Transform index using terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Elastic Cloud v 7.5.2. I am trying to transform the index, where i want the term count to be aggregated. In Kibana UI, Define Pivot does not have provision to take terms aggregation. How to achieve it? Is the version didn't support or we can achieve the same using Transform API?

we have a field eventType which will have values like task-started, task-completed, task-inprogress. Each document will have an jobId and each job can have multiple tasks. I need to transform the index to a new index in such a way where task-started, task-completed and task-inprogress will be separate field and it will have value count aggregated to it.

Our ultimate goal, in Kibana we need to show additional columns which will have percentage and ratio of these task fields.

Comment: "i want the term count": as in unique terms (= cardinality) or counting the number of values (= value_count)?

Comment: Counting the number of values.. I will edit the question for more clarity

Comment: Do you really need a Transform for that? I feel like you could easily do that with TSVB (probably as a gauge, where you have the total number of tasks and the tasks in a specific state)

Comment: We want data table.. Could you explain how to achieve in TSVB?